# CanI use existing 110v conduit for adding new 220v outlet in basement?

Tags: conduit, 240v, extension

I live in the Chicago area. I'm adding a new 220v outlet to a corner of my basement (*for a 3000W sauna heater*).

The basement is finished so putting in new conduit above the ceiling would be challenging.

Am I able/allowed to use existing conduit with 110v and add in new wires for the 220V?

Comment: Yes, several circuits (typ. up to 4) can share a conduit.  Can you give us photos of what's inside each of the junction boxes along the route, so we can double-check conduit fill, derate etc.?

Comment: Can you provide us with how many circuits are in the existing conduit please?

Comment: When you get back here, perhaps everyone is assuming half inch ID, but if it's 3/4 that helps so check the conduit size and fill (what wires are in each conduit) all the way back to the panel.  Include wire size.

Answer (score 1):

The conduit fill and how many current carrying conductors would be the issue.

If there is less than 4 current carrying conductors for this conduit adding 2 more will not be a problem with derating standard 75 degree wire and components.

If the fill will allow this could be code compliant.

more than 6 and the derating schedule or fill may be at the limit.

It is ok to run 240v circuits in the same pipe with 120. A 120v circuit has 2 current carrying conductors hot and neutral, a 240v circuit has 2 carrying conductors hot and hot.

Answer (score 1):

To strictly answer your question, yes you can use existing conduit but you have a whole lot of data to gather before determining if you can use what's existing. You need to know what size conduit is installed, what type and how many wires are already installed in the conduit, What type and how many wires will be needed to serve your sauna. Once you get all the information, then you/we can tell you if it's possible to use your existing conduit.